# how to put data in Model with custom input

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using ASP.NET and MVC, I can use custom classes on text boxes to pass data from the View in to a Model, and back to my controller as follows:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.first_name, new { @class = "form-control", tabindex = 1 })
```

In this same way, I want to return a string from a custom drop down selector into `m.affiliation`.  My custom input is as follows:

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="affiliation" id="affiliation" style="margin-top:1em;" data-width="100%">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

How do I properly replace the above block of code with Razor to make sure that this data is passed in to the affiliation member of my Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you haven't done anything wrong if what you want is to pass the selected option to your model. The only thing missing is the option value. So, supposing your model has an `affiliation` property then you can do the following without the use of helpers...

```
<select name="affiliation">
      <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Or, you can achieve the same by using HTML Helpers...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.affiliation, new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem(){Text = "Option 1", Value = "Option 1"},
    new SelectListItem(){Text = "Option 2", Value = "Option 2"},
    new SelectListItem(){Text = "Option 3", Value = "Option 3"}
})
```

Or, if your model already includes the affiliation list as a `List<string>` or `IEnumarable<string>`...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.affiliation, Model.affiliations_list.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
           {
               Value = x,
               Text = x
           }))
```